# Why is my python virtual environments keep getting changed to my global environments

Tags: python, virtualenv

I have several projects that use python, so i use virtual environments for each of those projects. A lot of time i use 2 separate vscode to do my work and use both each virtual environments. When i done with my project, i deactivate both virtual environments. But sometimes one of project's virtual environment is referencing to my global environment variable. When it first happen, i just deleted my `.env` and start again. But it keeps doing the same every now and then. Why does that happen ? and what to do to prevent that ?

**NOTES**

I'm using `virtualenv env` command to start a virtual environment

Comment: `virtualenv` has a `--system-site-packages` option, is that what you are looking for?

Comment: no...im creating to isolate my env from the global and don't use `--system-site-packages` flag. And my project did just fine for 2 weeks, and then it started to already activate itself when i open my project and when `pip list` all my packages in global is in my virtual environment

Comment: What does _"is referencing to my global environment variable"_ actually mean? Which problem exactly are you trying to get help with? Environment variables which are not part of the virtual environment (like `PATH` and Python's `sys.path`) will be shared between environments.

Comment: by referencing i mean suddenly my environtment variable is filled with packages that belong to my global environtment